# Best way to use trigger to prevent deletion of a row where condition in another table is met?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-delete, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger to prevent the deletion of a row in table_1 if a condition in a table_2 row with the same table_1ID is met (table_2.status = 'ON').

I am not worried about deleting more than one row at a time.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your DELETE statement in table 1 can JOIN to table 2 on the ID, and you can add a where condition where table2.status <> 'ON'. This would delete all rows where status <> 'ON'. Is that along the lines of what you are looking for?

Comment: @DanielG I am not looking to delete rows but rather create a trigger that prevents the deletion of a row in table_1 if it has table_2.status of 'ON', whenever a delete is attempted.

Comment: @DanielG Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
create or replace function func_delete_table1()
returns trigger as 
$$
begin
    if exists (select 1 from table2 where table1_id = old.id and status = 'ON') then
        raise exception 'Cannot delete id % from table1 because the corresponding record in table2 has status ON', new.id;
    end if;
end
$$ language 'plgpsql';

create trigger trg_delete_table1 before delete on table1_id
for each row execute procedure func_delete_table1();
```

Note that, as commented by DanielG, you could also implement the whole logic in your `delete` statements:

```
delete from table1 t1
where 
    id = ?
    and not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.table1id = t2.id and t2.status = 'ON')
```